# Puddle vs Pool in different cases

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference, word-in-context

I wish to know two things here:

1. Is the word **puddle** still in use?
2. In which case do we call water on the ground *a puddle* and in which *a pool*? Except for the big swimming pools those don't count.

How about:

- *The children are playing in a pool.*
- *The children are plaing in a puddle.*

Or:

- *"Why is your shoe wet? I stepped into a puddle."*
- *"Why is your shoe wet? I stepped into a pool."*

Answer (score 5):

Living in Australia, I know *puddle* is a common word and often used. This may be different for other places.

With regards to your second question, it generally depends on size. Many definitions of *puddle* describe a puddle as being "a small pool". Technically that suggests that all puddles are pools, but not all pools are puddles. However, despite this, this not mean you can just use *pool* in place of *puddle*. One of the biggest reasons why is that without context, the singular *pool* will often be assumed to be referring to a swimming pool.

It's hard to quantify exactly how much water constitutes a puddle. I think any small area of water that is not deep enough to submerge your foot past your ankles would qualify as a puddle, but this is just my own estimation.

Looking at your first sample sentences (grammar fixes in italics):

> The children *are* playing in a pool.
>
> The children are *playing* in a puddle.

Without context, the first sentence to me suggests that the children are playing in a swimming pool of some kind. The second sentence suggests that the children are playing in a small pool of water. If you want to say that the children are playing in a pool bigger than a puddle, I would use the term **pool of water**.

> The children are playing in a **pool of water**.

Likewise, if you wanted to say you stepped into a pool bigger than a puddle, you can modify your second sentence in the same way.

> Why is your shoe wet? I stepped into a **pool of water**.

It may seem like a strange recommendation given that swimming pools contain water too, but it works because if you were referring to a swimming pool, you would simply say *pool* or *swimming pool*. This construction allows us to differentiate between the two. It also falls in line with how we refer to other non-water liquids that pool up, such as a *pool of blood*.

Comment: This is pretty consistent with Webster's definitions.  "Pool" alone isn't necessarily water (a small body of standing liquid or something resembling a pool, like a pool of light).  When it refers to water, it's a small **and rather deep** body of usually fresh water or a swimming pool.  If you're talking about something bigger and deeper than a puddle and not a swimming pool, "pool of water" is likely how it would be referred to.  M-W defines puddle as a very small pool of usually dirty or muddy water.  "dirty or muddy" isn't necessary.

Comment: This is pretty consistent with usage in the US, too. Here, any temporary, shallow body of water or other liquid can be called a puddle, possibly with an adjective to indicate size (e.g. *a small puddle* or *a really deep puddle*). We also have the same distinction between (swimming) *pool* and *pool of* (specified fluid).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer:

There's a book "I Can Jump Puddles", that was written by Alan Marshall, an Australian writer, and there's a film based on it which once was telecast on Russian TV by the title "Я умею прыгать через лужи" [(Jumping Over Puddles)](http://www.kino-teatr.ru/kino/movie/euro/89203/annot/). Although one can imagine someone jumping over pools, the small lakes, or pools of blood or small bodies of standing water or other liquid, can't they?